# R: Communicating Between Different Data Frames

Tags: r

In R, I have these 2 data frames that contain random coordinates :

```
# Load the geosphere library
library(geosphere)

set.seed(123)
# Set the number of rows in each data frame
n1 <- 20
n2 <- 30

# Set the mean longitude and latitude for New York
lon_mean <- -74.0060
lat_mean <- 40.7128

# Set the standard deviation for the longitude and latitude
lon_sd <- 0.1
lat_sd <- 0.1

# Simulate random data for df_1
df_1 <- data.frame(
  lon = rnorm(n1, lon_mean, lon_sd),
  lat = rnorm(n1, lat_mean, lat_sd)
)

# Simulate random data for df_2
df_2 <- data.frame(
  lon = rnorm(n2, lon_mean, lon_sd),
  lat = rnorm(n2, lat_mean, lat_sd)
)


# Remove duplicate rows from df_1
df_1_unique <- unique(df_1)
```

**My Question:** For each unique coordinate in df_1, I want to calculate the geographical distances between that coordinate and ALL coordinates within df_2.

I tried to do this with a loop procedure:

```
# Initialize an empty list to store the result
result <- vector("list", nrow(df_1))

# Calculate the distances
for (i in 1:nrow(df_1)) {
  # Initialize an empty vector to store the distances for the i-th coordinate in df_1
  distances <- numeric(nrow(df_2))
  
  for (j in 1:nrow(df_2)) {
    # Calculate the distance between the i-th coordinate in df_1 and the j-th coordinate in df_2
    distances[j] <- distHaversine(c(df_1[i, "lon"], df_1[i, "lat"]), c(df_2[j, "lon"], df_2[j, "lat"]))
  }
  
  # Store the distances for the i-th coordinate in df_1 in the result list
  result[[i]] <- distances
print(result[[i]])
}

#####

end = list()
for (i in 1:length(result))
{
    end[[i]] = data.frame(id = seq_along(result[[i]]), values = result[[i]], iteration = i)

}

final <- do.call(rbind, end)
```

**Now, to this final result, I am trying to add 4 columns:**

- long_1
- lat_1
- long_2
- lat_2

That is, when `final$iteration == i` then `long_1 = df_1[i,1]` and `lat_1 = df_1[1,i]` . And, `long_2 = df_2[1,j]` and `lat_1 = df_1[j,1]` .

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
# get unique values of iteration
iterations <- unique(final$iteration)

# create new columns for each unique value of iteration
for (i in iterations) {
  final$long_1[final$iteration == i] <- df_1[i, 1]
  final$lat_1[final$iteration == i] <- df_1[i, 2]
  final$long_2[final$iteration == i] <- df_2[final$id[final$iteration == i], 1]
  final$lat_2[final$iteration == i] <- df_2[final$id[final$iteration == i], 2]
}
```

**Can someone please tell me if I am doing this correctly?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing multiple loops, we may use `crossing` to expand the two datasets, apply `distHaversine` with `rowwise` attribute

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(geosphere)
library(stringr)
result2 <- crossing(df_1, df_2 %>%
  rename_with(~ str_c(.x, "_2"))) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(distances = distHaversine(c(lon, lat), c(lon_2, lat_2))) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
result2
# A tibble: 600 × 5
     lon   lat lon_2 lat_2 distances
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 -74.2  40.7 -74.2  40.8    13372.
 2 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.8    13275.
 3 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.8    14040.
 4 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.8    17541.
 5 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.7    10186.
 6 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.7    11751.
 7 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.8    14096.
 8 -74.2  40.7 -74.1  40.6    18080.
 9 -74.2  40.7 -74.0  40.7    13429.
10 -74.2  40.7 -74.0  40.7    14181.
# … with 590 more rows
```

---

If we are using the nested `for` loop, it can be done in a single loop

```
result <- data.frame()

# Calculate the distances
for (i in 1:nrow(df_1)) {  
  for (j in 1:nrow(df_2)) {    
    tmp <- distHaversine(c(df_1[i, "lon"], df_1[i, "lat"]), 
           c(df_2[j, "lon"], df_2[j, "lat"]))
    result <- rbind(result, data.frame(lon_1 = df_1$lon[i],
       lat_1 = df_1$lat[i], lon_2 = df_2$lon[j], 
      lat_2 = df_2$lat[j], distance = tmp))
  }
  }
```

-output

```
> dim(result)
[1] 600   5
> result2 %>% 
  filter(round(lat, 2) == 40.61, round(lon, 2) == -74.06, 
      round(lon_2, 2) == -74.08)
# A tibble: 1 × 5
    lon   lat lon_2 lat_2 distances
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 -74.1  40.6 -74.1  40.7     6520.
> head(result, 1)
      lon_1    lat_1     lon_2   lat_2 distance
1 -74.06205 40.60602 -74.07547 40.6637 6520.188
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just do this:

```
library(dplyr)
cross_join(df_1_unique, df_2) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dist = distHaversine(c(lon.x, lat.x), c(lon.y, lat.y)))
```

Output:

```
   lon.x lat.x lon.y lat.y   dist
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -74.1  40.6 -74.1  40.7  6520.
 2 -74.1  40.6 -74.0  40.5 14137.
 3 -74.1  40.6 -74.1  40.8 23837.
 4 -74.1  40.6 -73.8  40.6 23404.
 5 -74.1  40.6 -73.9  40.6 15528.
 6 -74.1  40.6 -74.1  40.8 23782.
 7 -74.1  40.6 -74.0  40.7  8818.
 8 -74.1  40.6 -74.1  40.6  1878.
 9 -74.1  40.6 -73.9  40.7 17929.
10 -74.1  40.6 -74.0  40.7 11098.
# … with 590 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```